# Php reading Foxpro DBF file

Tags: php, odbc, xampp, oledb, dbf

I need to do a record search and display in a Foxpro dbf file using PHP. My dbf file name icitem.DBF, i am using ODBC and OLEDB methods but both return errors.

Method 1:
I manage to install the foxpro ODBC driver and create a system DNS, below is my php script and output.

php script:

```
$odbc = odbc_connect ("myDB", "" , "");
$strsql= "SELECT * FROM icitem WHERE CAT=820";
$query = odbc_exec($odbc, $strsql) or die (odbc_errormsg());
odbc_close($odbc);
```

output:
Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Cannot open file c:\xampp\htdocs\db\stock.dbc., SQL state S1000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\hottemp\index.php on line 9
[Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Cannot open file c:\xampp\htdocs\db\stock.dbc.

Method 2:
I install the microsoft ole db provider for visual foxpro 9 at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839

php script:

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") ;
$conn->Open('Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=C:\xampp\htdocs\db;
Collating Sequence=machine;');
$query="SELECT * FROM icitem WHERE CAT=820";
$conn->Execute($query);
$conn->Close();
```

output:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '**Source:** Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro
**Description:** Cannot open file c:\xampp\htdocs\db\stock.dbc.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(8): com->Execute('SELECT * FROM i...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 8

Look like both output required the stock.dbc instead of icitem.dbf? I only have the icitem.dbf and icitem.fpt.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but to help others...

I too had this issue. I solved it by using this library: http://adodb.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Download microsoft foxpro driver and use

```html
$dsn="Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=e:\my-dbfs-folder\;Exclusive=No; Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=YES;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;";
  
$conn=odbc_connect($dsn, '', '');
 
if (!$conn)
 {
    echo (die(odbc_error()));
 } 
else{
  echo 'BENGGA!!!!';
}
```

That's it!!!